# Python nested function call another function in class

Tags: python-3.x

I've a class

```
class AClass():
    def a(self):
       ... code ...
    def b(self):
       ... code ...
    def c(self):
       def d():
           ... call a() ...
           ... call b() ...
       ... call d() ...
```

How can I call function a and b from function d of c?

Comment: Did `self.a` `self.b` not work?

Comment: no, not working. can't declare d as a "def d(self):"

Comment: you don't need to declare d as `def d(self)` calling d() inside of c method when d have a() and b() is the same as calling a() and b().

Comment: I didn't declared d as def d(self): but also I can't call a and b from d. when I run the app as debug mode with breakpoint, it is calling a and b. but when I run the app without breakpoint, it is running neither a nor b.

Comment: I'm able to call a() and b() using self.a() and self.b(). Of course, I'm just using a dummy class, so it's probably a different problem entirely?

Comment: yes, you right, it is another issue. and I found it is QtCore.QTimer(). I solved as self.timer = QtCore.QTimer() self.timer.timeout.connect(d). before that, I used timer = QtCore.QTimer() timer.timeout.connect(d). in the def d() I call timer, again. Thanks for you time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AClass():
    def a(self):
       print('A')
    def b(self):
       print('B')
    def c(self):
       def d():
           self.a()    # because 'self' is defined in the enclosing scope...
           self.b()    # ...it's valid to use within our definition of d()
       d()
```

Note that the definition of the function `d()` gets re-evaluated and re-compiled essentially *every time `c()` is run**. Like any other function, the variables defined in the enclosing scope are valid to use, so we can call methods on the `self` that was passed into C:

```
>>> inst = AClass()
>>> inst.c()
A
B
```

As we can see, both `a()` and `b()` were called successfully.

---

*It's more complicated than that, but the just-in-time-compilation process in python is beyond the scope of this answer

Comment: This is what I get from doing my own test, maybe OP problem is more than just this implementation?